# Breaking inside async methods without breaking inside try catches

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, .net-core, breakpoints

I've read many topics that stated the way to breakpoint first-chance exceptions in `async` methods is to "Enable all CLR Runtime Exceptions" in the Visual Studio debugger. The problem is this has the unintended side effect of breaking inside every `try/catch` which just makes debugging harder again. When looking for answers to this issue, they all stated to "Disable all CLR Runtime Exceptions" in the Visual Studio Debugger.

Is there a way to fix one of these issues without causing the other?

I'm aware that there's a lot of special handling of how to `try/catch` exceptions inside Tasks but I'm hoping there's at least some sort of compromise.

**Example Code:**

```
static void Main() {
    try {
        // When all CLR exceptions are enabled, we end up breaking here.
        throw new Exception();
    } catch { }
    AsyncMethod().GetAwaiter().GetResult();// or .Wait()
}

static async Task AsyncMethod() {
    // When all CLR exceptions are disabled, we end up breaking in Main.
    // (No matter how deep the async calls go)
    throw new Exception();
}
```

What's strange, is a few months ago this issue didn't occur. `async` methods were breaking on first-chance and exceptions in `try/catch`s were not breaking. I'm confused how this worked fine back then.

Comment: Good question, I'm going to blame magic. async state machines are weird, the debugger must do a lot of work to pretend they are simple methods. The debugger has been improved a few times, changing the behaviour.